# Controlling Material UI Inputs Not Working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I created a modal to use for editing records, but I can’t seem to get the inputs to be controlled.  I have tried everything I have seen online about controlling a Material UI input field, but every time I open the edit modal I get this error:
*”Warning: A component is changing an uncontrolled input to be controlled. This is likely caused by the value changing from undefined to a defined value, which should not happen. Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component.”*

I have added a defaultValue to the inputs, but it doesn’t seem to help.  How do I control these inputs and stop this error?

***editModal.js***

```
<Form onSubmit={handleSubmit} open={openModal}> 
     <Grid container spacing={0}>
         <Grid item xs={6}>
             <Input
                 name="tankName"
                 label="Tank Name"
                 value={item.tankName}
                 onChange={handleInputChange}
                 error={errors.tankName}
             />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={6}>
            <Checkbox
                label="Allow Corrective Actions"
                name="allowCorActionRecom"
                value={item.allowCorActionRecom}
                onChange={handleInputChange}
             />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
   <Grid>
       <div>
           <Button
               type="submit"
               text="Submit"
               onClick={editRecord}
            />
            <Button
                text="Cancel" 
                onClick={()=>{setOpenModal(false)}}
            />
       </div>
    </Grid>
</Form>
)}
```

***input.js***

```
export default function Input(props) {
    const { error=null, label, name, onChange, value, ...other } = props;
    return (
        <TextField
            label={label}
            name={name}
            value={value}
            defaultValue=''
            onChange={onChange}
            {...other}
            {...(error && {error:true,helperText:error})}
        />
    )
}
```

***checkbox.js***

```
export default function Checkbox(props) {
    const { name, label, value, onChange } = props;
    const convertToDefEventPara = (name, value) => ({
        target: {
            name, value
        }
    })

    return (
        <FormControl>
            <FormControlLabel
                control={<MuiCheckbox
                    name={name}
                    color="primary"
                    checked={value}
                    defaultValue="unchecked"
                    onChange={e => onChange(convertToDefEventPara(name, e.target.checked))}
                />}
                label={label}
            />
        </FormControl>
    )
}
```

***formFuctions.js***

```
export function FormFunctions(validateOnChange = false, validate) {
    const [values, setValues] = useState('');
    const [errors, setErrors] = useState({});

    const handleInputChange = e => {
        const { name, value } = e.target
        setValues({
            ...values,
            [name]: value
        })
        if (validateOnChange)
            validate({ [name]: value })
    };
    return {errors, handleInputChange, setErrors, setValues, values}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using

```
value={value}
defaultValue=''

and

checked={value}
defaultChecked={false}
```

I used a ternary to force the inputs to have values, which seems to have corrected my issue.

```
value={value === undefined ? '' : value}

and

checked={value === undefined ? false : value}
```

So far I have found no issues with this solution.